# my github actions passing unit test when it should fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, github-actions

I have set up my github actions with a test task which should run the test project and check if all test are fine. I implemented a failing test to test if the action works. My test fail as expected when I run the test on my local machine. When i push my code and it triggers a workflow action on github, the test task runs and doesnt fail which it should, it passes.

Here is my github action:

```
name: Build Test Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dev
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: proj
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: proj/publish
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE: ${{ secrets.proj_0a91 }}
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: PROJ
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1.0.0
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
[Test]
    

public void Test1()
        {
            var result = 2 + 2;

            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(5));
        }
```

any help would be greatful!

Comment: What says the log of your GitHub Action run?

Comment: fixed the issue - i used the command dotnet test instead of dotnet test --no-build